# Horizontally and vertically center columns in longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable

Given the following longtable:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,longtable, lipsum}
\begin{document}
Text First Line
\vspace{23cm}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{|m{1.5cm}|m{3.5cm}|p{13.5cm}|}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \centering \textbf{Heading}} \\
    \hline
    Item 1 & Item 2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Item 3 (Long)} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \centering \textbf{Heading (continued)}} \\
    \hline
    Item 1 & Item 2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Item 3 (Long)} \\
    \endhead
    A & B & \lipsum[2] \\ \hline
    A & B & \lipsum[3] \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following graphic:
[image: Table Image]

Is there an easy way to style the columns such that the cells marked Item 1, Item 2, A and B are centered horizontally as well as vertically? The solution should also be such that it can be done without recompiling several times.

**Some Context:**
I have tried using xltabular, and taken a look at some other packages like ltxtable, but due to external requirements (the file will be generated from within an app, and can't be arbitrarily recompiled, etc), they do not seem feasible. For whatever reason, when trying to include xltabular via the programmatic call to pdflatex, `xltabular.sty cannot be found` is shown, despite xltabular being installed on the PC.

Comment: To vertically center, use m type columns for all columns.

Comment: Assuming you don't need automatic linebreaks in the first to columns: `\begin{longtable}{|Wc{1.5cm}|Wc{3.5cm}|m{13.5cm}|}`

Comment: @leandriis 
That second suggestion works perfectly, thanks

Comment: Try `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Item 1}` etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for another solution - the first comment's solution gave some difficulty when used locally (worked fine on Overleaf though)

Comment: @leandriis, better is to write `W{c}{1.5cm}` instead `Wc{1.5cm}`, regardless, that result is the same. Syntax is more clear and follows explanation in the `array` package documentation.